# Give $2$ matrices $A$ and $B$, that are real, with size $n$($n\ge 2$) and satisfy $AB- nA - B$ = $0$. Show that $AB^{2n} = B^{2n}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Give $2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ that are real with size $n$ ($n\ge 2$) and satisfy $AB- nA - B$ = $0$. Show that $AB^{2n}$ = $B^{2n}A$ (Both $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular matrices)

(this comes from a mocking test version of the final exam of my linear algebra course, and normally the hardest task to categorize the level of the learner)

I have tried to use algebraical manipulation, but it doesn't work, and I tried to use mathematical induction, but it didn't work either. Can anyone help me with this question?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need mathematical induction. Let $X=A-I$. Then the given condition as well as the hypothesis can be rewritten as $X(B-nI)=nI$ and $XB^{2n}=B^{2n}X$ respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$nI = AB-nA - B +nI = A(B-nI) - (B-nI) = (A-I)(B-nI)$$
so by Binet-Cauchy theorem we also have
$$nI = (B-nI)(A-I) = BA-nA-B+nI \implies BA-nA-B = 0.$$
But since $AB-nA - B=0$, it has to be $AB = BA$. Therefore in particular $AB^{2n} = B^{2n}A$ holds.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer